# Clauses of purpose: "for + -ing" or "to-infinitive

Tags: infinitives, gerunds, clauses

In the following sentence, how should the clause of purpose be introduced?

> - In addition to normal maintenance, there are additional costs associated with interventions that may be required **to meet/for
>     meeting** minimum safety standards

Comment: I am sure the Q of "infinitive or gerund" has been asked on this site before.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct:

> "Interventions that may be required to meet minimum safety standards."
>
> "Interventions that may be required for meeting minimum safety standards"

- Sarah went to the computer lab to print out her research report.
- This function on the air conditioner is for reducing humidity.

Clauses of purpose are usually introduced by

> - "to" + infinitive
> - "in order to" + infinitive
> - "in order that"
> - "so as (not) to" + infinitive
> - "so that" + an auxiliary verb (can, could, will, would...)
> - "in case" + present simple
> - "for" + noun
> - "for" + "-ing"
> - "with a view to", "for the purpose of", "with the intention of" + "-ing"
> - "prevent + noun/pronoun + from + "-ing". (negative purpose)

see more at http://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/clause-purpose

Comment: Do both of them have exactly the same meaning?

Comment: @Robbo They may have exactly the same meaning depending on context.  "required to meet" can be ambiguous ("interventions that will have to be used x interventions that will have to be improved) To avoid ambiguity (if context isn't clear enough) you can use "in order to": "Interventions that may be required in order to meet minimum safety standards."

Comment: There’s also the *for him to verb* construct, which [John Lawler calls the *for-to* complementizer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/278319/2085). In spirit but not in form this works a bit like Portuguese personal infinitives, which are inflected for person but not tense, and which can serve as the object of a preposition.

Comment: @tchrist  good call.