# What does this question ask? What is the meaning of "for the law" in this sentence?

Tags: infinitives, for-to-complementizers

The sentence is:

"Is it ever justifiable for the law to treat some people as inferior to others?"

Can anyone explain the meaning of this question? I am confused about especially the "for the law" part. Is "law" the subject here? Or does it ask that if treating some people as inferior to others is justifiable or not in front of the law?

Comment: "for the law" is not a constituent phrase in this sentence. It should be looked as "Is it ever justifiable for: *the law to treat some people as inferior to others*?"

Comment: @MarkBeadles thanks for the answer but I still don't get the meaning. Could you explain what the question asks?

Comment: Your last sentence pretty much answers it.

Comment: *Is it ever justifiable for (something) to (do something).* Now can you understand it?

Comment: [Related and possible duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/278319/2085).

Answer (score 2):

> "Is it ever justifiable for the law to treat some people as inferior to others?"

can be paraphrased as:

> Is [the law treating some people as inferior] ever justifiable?

where "the law" is the subject of an embedded clause.