# Does a ver­bal noun turn back into a verb when mod­iﬁed by an ad­verb?

Tags: ambiguity, parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis, gerund-phrases, grammatical-roles

Here *singing* is a noun:

1. I like singing.

But what about here?

2. I like singing loudly.

*Loudly* is still an ad­verb, right? But *singing* is still 
be­hav­ing like a noun, right?

So which is it, a noun or a verb? How can it be­have like a noun when it
gets mod­i­ﬁed by an ad­verb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your sec­ond ex­am­ple, the ob­ject of the verb *like* is the
gerund clause *singing loudly*, which serves as [the NP ob­ject of the
verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase) here. The head of that
clause is the verb *singing* as mod­i­fied by the ad­verb *loudly*. Like an in­fini­tive clause, a gerund clause is [a non-fi­nite verb
clause](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/gerund.html) that can serve as an NP when em­bed­ded. Which
of the two pos­si­ble verb forms you choose does­n’t mat­ter in
this case, as these are equiv­a­lent in meaning:

1. I like singing loudly.
2. I like to sing loudly.

Had your verb been a tran­si­tive one, you could have added ob­ject
com­ple­ments to your clauses:

3. I like call­ing her loudly.
4. I like to call her loudly.

Those ad­mit some ad­ver­bial mo­tion, but only within the non-fi­nite verb clause:

5. I like loudly call­ing her.
6. I like to loudly call her.

You can even have a dif­fer­ent sub­ject in that clause than you had
in the main sen­tence:

7. I like her call­ing me loudly.
8. I like for her to call me loudly.

No­tice how when the *to*-in­fini­tive clause has a dif­fer­ence
sub­ject, you need to stick a spe­cial *for-com­ple­men­tizer*
there when us­ing the clause as an NP as we do here.
Read more
about these po­tent­ially cu­ri­ous com­ple­men­tiz­ers [in this an­swer by
Pro­fes­sor Law­ler](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/278319/2085)
or in [these lec­ture notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/gerund.html) from his web­site, or in the notes from this
more tech­ni­cal [**lin­guis­tics lec­ture** on the struc­ture of
clauses](https://gawron.sdsu.edu/syntax/lectures/lec6.htm).

## Deep Struc­tures

I fear that un­til you move on from sim­plis­tic anal­y­sis fo­cussing merely
on parts of speech to higher level anal­y­sis of gram­mat­i­cal
struc­tures and how these em­bed as syn­tac­tic con­stituents, you
will of­ten find your­self stuck with seem­ing para­doxes that
can­not be re­solved so long as parts of speech are all you think of.
That’s be­cause hu­man lan­guage uses these syn­tac­tic
struc­tures, so no anal­y­sis of the for­mer can ex­empt the
lat­ter and sur­vive.

Embed­ded deep struc­tures are a
fun­da­men­tal part of how hu­man lan­guage works.

Answer (score 1):

> *I like singing*

is strictly speaking ambiguous, but the verb is the salient interpretation (c.f. "I like to sing").

Noun interpretation can be forced by adjectival premodification, as in "I like occasional singing".

In *I like singing loudly*, "singing" is a verb serving as head of the non-finite clause "singing loudly", which is complement of "like".