# Is "someone would love for this to..." correct?

Tags: prepositions, infinitives

I've recently used the phrase "xxx would love for yyy to be zzz"; example [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1040690/how-do-i-send-emails-from-a-different-domain/1042208#1042208), "spammers would really love for this to be possible".

Is this phrasing grammatically correct?

I'm sure I've heard/read it somewhere, and it "feels" good (I'm not a native English speaker, but I know/read/write/speak English at a level where I usually can spot grammatically wrong usage instinctively).
But on this I'm not sure, thus I'm asking.

I'm especially concerned about the usage of "love for x to be y" here, and the whole sentence construction.

I know I could have said "spammers would love this to be possible", without "for"; but I want to know, is the form with "for" correct or at least permitted? Or should I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This construction is a good example of why linguists call the infinitive complementizer
"the ***for ... to*** complementizer".

Infinitives are clauses, with subjects and verbs. The Verb Phrase in an infinitive is [marked with *to*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/278319/15299). The subject Noun Phrase in an infinitive is frequently missing from the clause, but when it's present, it's often marked with *for*. The **for** is normally only required when the infinitive clause is a subject itself; any infinitive subject has to be marked with *for* to keep it from being taken as the subject.  E.g,

- *They want to leave early.*
- *They want you to leave early.*
- *They want for you to leave early.*
- *It would be a mistake to leave early.*
- *It would be a mistake for you to leave early.*
- *For you to leave early would be a mistake.*
- **You to leave early would be a mistake.*

The structure with *would love* takes a full infinitive object clause, with NP (the second NP in the sentence) and VP, each marked with their respective complementizer:

- *`NP₁` would love* [ np [ s [ np ***for** `NP₂`*] [ vp ***to** `VP`*] ] ]

The formulation *for `yyy` to be `zzz`* is just one type of infinitive clause, with an auxiliary *be* and a predicate adjective or noun phrase `zzz`. Any clause can be made into an infinitive, unless it has a modal auxiliary.

Comment: I'd say that 'They want for you to leave early' is heading towards unidiomatic, far less common than 'They want you to leave early'. Raw Google data is 0 : 900 000.