# What is the difference between a bare infinitive and an infinitive?

Tags: grammar, infinitives, bare-infinitive

One teacher told me that the bare infinitive cannot be used as the direct object of a modal verb because it is not a noun. But, aren't infinitives with or without "to" infinitives?

Comment: Who told you that infinitives (of any kind) were nouns?

Comment: There must be more to that statement! What is an object of a modal verb?

Comment: Modal verbs don't have direct objects; they modify the meaning of another verb, which has to be in infinitive form.

Comment: To alphabet. 

I hear all the time that infinitives are verbal nouns, also called verbals. Here is a link to one of the pages that does this: https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/verbs/verbals/

Comment: Yes, '_to_-infinitival clauses' and bare infinitival clauses are the two kinds of infinitival clause.  Clauses of any kind cannot function as objects of any verb, lexical or modal. However, they freely function as complements of other verbs of any kind.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/613488/2085).  You're confusing parts of speech like nouns and verbs and adjectives with grammatical functions like subject and object and modifier. Phrases and clauses never have a part of speech, no matter their grammatical function.

Comment: @StimRoe Infinitivals are not 'verbal nouns', despite what you may read elsewhere. Trad grammar talks of verbal nouns being 'gerunds'.

Comment: In *I can drive,* the verb *drive* is not the direct object of *can,* but is the main verb of the sentence, which is used in conjunction with the modal verb *can.* On the other hand, in French,  in the sentence *je peux conduire* (meaning *I can drive*), *conduire* is indeed the direct object of *peux*. This difference of terminology can confuse people learning another language.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be based on a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is in the context.

- *Infinitive* is a morphological term, referring to a particular form of the verb (the verb form that ends in *-en* in German *Ich muss gehen*, and *-r* in Spanish *Tengo que irme*). [English infinitive verb forms have no special mark, and resemble the present in almost every case, so you can't tell the infinitive form of an English verb from a present tense form](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/278319/15299). Since verb forms are single words (with or without inflections), there is nothing to be "bare" in the sense of "missing something".
- *Bare infinitive,* by contrast, is a syntactic term; a bare infinitive is a construction, consisting of one or more words in a particular pattern, like *the* in *the dog* -- *the* has to come before *dog*, and *the dog* is a noun phrase, not just a noun. Similarly, *to leave* in *I want to leave* is a verb phrase, and the *to* marks it as a verb phrase, just like *the* marks *the dog* as a noun phrase.

In this syntactic context, "bare infinitive" means an infinitive VP without an introductory *to*. This construction is licensed by some verbs, including all modal auxiliaries, plus small verbs like *let* (**Let me to go!*), and optional in many cases (*Help me (to) get him out*). Note that a "bare infinitive" does indeed have  an infinitive verb form, but it also includes the rest of the VP that verb heads.

If you add the categories "verb form" and "construction" to your terminology, a lot of the confusion goes away. As long as you can tell the difference and maintain it consistently.

Comment: I think it would be clearer to say that English doesn't have an infinitival form of the verb in the way that, say, French does. "To succeed", for example, is not a verb; it's two words, the subordinator "to" and the verb "succeed".

Comment: Yes, it's a construction. A verb phrase, in this case.