# Can you tell me the difference between the bare infinitive and the base form of a verb?

Tags: grammar, verbs, syntactic-analysis, infinitives

I heard my teacher stating that the base form of a verb is not an infinitive itself, but it is used to construct one of the two forms of infinitives.

---

**Edit note**

This question has been linked to a previous one of mine. However, in that question I was asking about the difference between infinitives and bare infinitives. This is a different question altogether.

Comment: *go*: base form of the verb *go.* *I go*:  conjugated form of the verb *go* (same in spelling and pronunciation as the base form). *Let me go*: the bare infinitive of the verb *go*. *I want to go*: the to-infinitive of the verb *go*. So while *I go* has the same spelling and pronuciation as the infinitive, it's **not** the infinitive. But all of these are examples of the base form of the verb *go*.

Comment: This appears to be a comment on the answer to your original question.

Comment: The lexical base is identical with the plain form that is used to construct infinitival clauses, subjunctives and imperatives.

Comment: There is no difference, what is different is *usage* or *grammar*.

Comment: Different people use different terms, and often there is no difference. In English, there is no difference between "infinitive" and "base form" -- they're both verb forms -- but "bare infinitive" is syntactic ("bare" because no complementizer _to_) and the others are  morphological. [I'm getting tired of answering this question.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/613667/15299) Terminology differs and there is often no difference between terms besides author's preference.

Comment: @JohnLawler But English has no infinitive form, so we can hardly say there is no difference between 'infinitive' and 'base form'. As it happens, the lexical base is identical with the 'plain form' that is used to construct infinitival clauses, subjunctives and imperatives.

Comment: The infinitive form has merged with the present form. Just as the past and the past participle forms have merged in all regular verbs and many irregulars. Languages change, and definitions are always inadequate to describe data. You can call them anything you want, but you can't go from terminology to "therefore" or "hardly".

Comment: @JohnLawler You keep talking of the 'infinitive form’, but, as I claimed in a previous thread, English does not have an infinitive form of the verb. Take the verb "walk", for example: the plain present and the plain form have the same shape, "walk", but they are different inflectional forms of the verb. Similarly for the preterite and past participle; they share the same shape "walked", but they are different inflectional forms.

Comment: @BillJ You may claim all you want, but that's just the way you want to talk about it, not a universal principle. You talk the way you want, I'll talk the way I want; even though **someone** may be **wrong** on the internet, I can live with that.

Comment: @JohnLawler But it's a fact that English does not have an infinitive form of the verb in the way that, say, French does. It would be flat wrong or at least misleading to say that it does. Which explains why the term 'split infinitive' is misleading: there's nothing to 'split'! I don't see the relevance of the Internet.

Comment: What do you want to call the verb form _be_? It's the only distinctive infinitive form left in English, but it's awfly common, and always called an infinitive in grammars and textbooks. I used the phrase "infinitive form" because it's a common in such venues, which is where our readers are from. I don't care what you call it; I think the fetish for naming tenses, constructions, and parts of speech is silly. Things always change, and you can't have a name for everything. And even if you did, what good does it do? It's just another insect on a pin.

Answer (score 6):

The *base form* or *plain form* of the verb occurs in four different constructions. The imperative, the subjunctive, the bare infinitival construction and the *to*-infinitival construction. For many linguists, the *to*-infinitival construction is actually a case of a non-finite auxiliary verb, *to*, taking a bare infinitival complement. You won't find that analysis in any school or undergraduate curriculum however. So, for our purposes, here are examples of the four constructions where we might see the base/plain form of the verb:

1. **Be** quiet! (imperative)
2. I demand that you **be** quiet! (subjunctive)
3. You should **be** quiet. (bare infinitive)
4. I want you to **be** quiet. (*to*-infinitive)

Each of these uses the base/plain form of the verb, but they are not all bare infinitives!

Comment: I suspect the asker is confusing inflectional morphology as applied to single lexemes with multiword syntactic constituents. *We watched him **leave town secretly**.*

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you subscribe to the non-finite auxiliary verb "to" analysis?

Comment: @user424874 It's the analysis I'm most sympathetic towards.

Answer (score 1):

In comments John Lawler wrote:

> Different people use different terms, and often there is no difference. In English, there is no difference between "infinitive" and "base form" -- they're both verb forms -- but "bare infinitive" is syntactic ("bare" because no complementizer *to*) and the others are  morphological. [I'm getting tired of answering this question.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/613667/15299) Terminology differs and there is often no difference between terms besides author's preference.

> The infinitive form has merged with the present form. Just as the past and the past participle forms have merged in all regular verbs and many irregulars. Languages change, and definitions are always inadequate to describe data. You can call them anything you want, but you can't go from terminology to "therefore" or "hardly".

Answer (score 1):

In comments BillJ wrote:

> The lexical base is identical with the plain form that is used to construct infinitival clauses, subjunctives and imperatives.

> @JohnLawler But English has no infinitive form, so we can hardly say there is no difference between 'infinitive' and 'base form'. As it happens, the lexical base is identical with the 'plain form' that is used to construct infinitival clauses, subjunctives and imperatives.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you tell me the difference between the bare infinitive and the base form of a verb?

The term "bare infinitive" is a grammatical category.

"I can **jump** the fence"

"The base, or root, form" is a linguistic term and teaching aid that demonstrates the root from which the verb arose and which can often be used to conjugate the verb.

The verb "to jump" is conjugated from its base form "jump-" I jump; he jump**s**; jump**ed**, have jump**ed**.

[twinkl.co.uk/teaching-wiki](https://www.twinkl.co.uk/teaching-wiki/base-form-verbs)

> What is the base form verb (or the root form)?
> A base form is the simplest form of a verb, without any subject pronouns like ‘I’ or ‘we’ attached. You’ll often hear it referred to as the infinitive or root form of a verb - it’s what we change when we want to make it agree with different tenses and subject pronouns. When you search for a verb in a dictionary or thesaurus, this is the form you’ll find.
>
> Though they’re functionally identical (except for the 3rd person singular), the base form is different from the present form of a verb in that it doesn’t appear with a subject pronoun. This is the difference between ‘I write’ and ‘write’.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment Peter Shor wrote:

> *go*: base form of the verb *go.* *I go*:  conjugated form of the verb *go* (same in spelling and pronunciation as the base form). *Let me go*: the bare infinitive of the verb *go*. *I want to go*: the to-infinitive of the verb *go*. So while *I go* has the same spelling and pronuciation as the infinitive, it's **not** the infinitive. But all of these are examples of the base form of the verb *go*.